# Visual Studio 2008 build errors 

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to compile an old project that was originally designed for Visual Studio 2008 SP0 (I'm using SP1 now). I'm getting these errors.

```
    Error   51  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "unsigned long __cdecl GetDeviceState(enum DEVICES_ENUM,enum DEVICE_STATE_ENUM &,int &)" (?GetDeviceState@@YAKW4DEVICES_ENUM@@AAW4DEVICE_STATE_ENUM@@AAH@Z) referenced in function _Get1394DeviceStatus   Raw1394api.obj  raw1394api
    Error   52  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "unsigned long __cdecl SetDeviceState(enum DEVICES_ENUM,enum DEVICE_STATE_ENUM,int &,int &)" (?SetDeviceState@@YAKW4DEVICES_ENUM@@W4DEVICE_STATE_ENUM@@AAH2@Z) referenced in function _Set1394DeviceStatus    Raw1394api.obj  raw1394api
    Error   53  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl InstallDevice(wchar_t *)" (?InstallDevice@@YA_NPA_W@Z) referenced in function _InstallDriver    Raw1394api.obj  raw1394api
    Error   54  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl UninstallDevice(void)" (?UninstallDevice@@YA_NXZ) referenced in function _UninstallDriver   Raw1394api.obj  raw1394api
    Error   55  fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals f:\InfoSelect My Documents\Zurvan on Windows\raw1394 for Windows by Dmitry\test\raw1394src\Debug\raw1394api.dll raw1394api
```

Comment: I think it's fairly simple to assume that his question is: "How do I fix the errors?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to check the files mentioned in the last row.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to install the latest Windows SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set DLL/LIB location contains missing symbols in project setting.
Or if your project uses DirectX (or XNA), you should install DirectX SDK first.